# Xpath required for an input text field where id is keep changing

Tags: selenium-webdriver

html portion:

```
<td class="nowrapTd" id="yui_3_2_0_1_15137599176392131">
<input size="32" maxlength="128" id="yui_3_2_0_1_15137599176392170" type="text"></td>
```

I have tried below xpath but did not get success so could you please help me here

```
By.xpath("//‌​[starts-with(@id,'yui_')]");
By.xpath("//input[@type='text'][starts-with(@id,'yui_')]");
```

Comment: HTML CODE:-   
<td class="nowrapTd" id="yui_3_2_0_1_15137599176392131">
<input size="32" maxlength="128" id="yui_3_2_0_1_15137599176392170" type="text"></td>

Comment: Tried , By.xpath("//‌​[starts-with(@id,'yui_')]") but did not get success

Comment: Also tried,  By.xpath("//input[@type='text'][starts-with(@id,'yui_')]"); still not get success

Comment: Some of the selectors seems ok, are you finding any element in the page manually using these selectors? Maybe the selector is good but it is finding another element before the one you need or a hidden one OR maybe you need a wait. Please try this selector in the page manually.

Answer (score 0):

The `<input>` tag is within the `<td>` tag. So the `Xpath` for the `input` field would be :

```
By.xpath("//input[starts-with(@id,'yui_') and @type='text']")
```

Comment: Try the updated `xpath`. Moreover `not working` doesn't throws any light on whats happening. Can you update the question with your recent trials and the error stack trace?